# How to get all auto generated foreign key names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following my previously asked question: I'm trying to get all auto-generated foreign keys of a database.

In my case (it must be the typical behaviour of SQL Server 2014), all the generated foreign key constraints have a name like `FK__TableFrom__TableTo__1F63A897`, where the end of the key name (`1F63A897`) is autogenerated. And all the well named foreign keys are like `FK__TableFrom__TableTo`. So I need to target all foreign key with the random string in the end of the name of the key

I tried with the `LIKE` operator but cannot achieve my goal.

The most preferred output should be:

```
SCHEMA_NAME     |   TABLE_NAME      |   FOREIGN_KEY_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
...             |   ...             |   ID
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily consult the `sys.foreign_keys` catalog view for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE is_system_named = 1
```

This returns **all** foreign key constraints that are "system-named", e.g. where you didn't provide an explicit constraint name when creating them.